# PTIJ: Electoral College in the Torah?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In these turbulent times where our American brethren fight among themselves on whether or not to keep using the Electoral College, I have a question:

It says in the Tur ([Choshen Mishpat 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tur%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.1.1?vhe=Choshen_Mishpat,_Vilna,_1923&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)):

> "...lies have no legs [to stand on] but truth is the foundation and it is a big pillar for all things. And similarly, peace, as they say in Avot (Pirkei Avot 3:2), “One should pray for the peace of the government, for were it not for the fear of government, people would swallow each other alive.”"

We see here a clear connection between truth and peace and government. Perhaps the reason that Americans are fighting is because they don't see truth in the Electoral College and are unwilling to continue living a lie.

So, is the Electoral College truth or not?

Or in other words,

?אלקטורל קולג' מן התורה מנין

Where do we find the Electoral College in the Torah (with the Torah being truth of course, as is said ([Tehillim 119:142](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Psalms.119.142?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) "צִדְקָתְךָ֣ צֶ֣דֶק לְעוֹלָ֑ם וְֽתוֹרָתְךָ֥ אֱמֶֽת׃" - "Your righteousness is eternal, your Torah is true)?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Wow, three downvotes already! People sure do hate the EC...

Comment: Anyone of the downvoters want to actually voice your hatred?

Comment: I didn't vote on this, but maybe the downvoters are thinking about the Purim Torah policy. Yes, you're *inviting* a "distinctly Torah style analysis of some secular issue", but your question doesn't contain any.

Comment: @Fred oh. Hmmm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hinted to here, in Yichezkel 30:5:

> וּבְנֵ֖י אֶ֣רֶץ הַבְּרִ֑ית׃

We know that the US is called ארצות הברית, so each state is one ארץ הברת. But each state is addressed by the term בני, so it has multiple representatives. Those are the electoral college.

The pasuk talks about their downfall, so maybe we'll overturn this silliness.

## Edit:

Davar Acher (a better explain in medrashim jargon)

> וּבְנֵ֖י אֶ֣רֶץ הַבְּרִ֑ית אִתָּ֖ם בַּחֶ֥רֶב יִפֹּֽלוּ
>
> "And the representatives of the State with them will poll by the knife"

"By the knife" means as a block, that all of the representatives of the State will vote as a single block.

According to this the EC is here to stay. :(

Comment: Though seemingly this talks about only one state. That's not enough to overturn the EC.